# Service account Drive App without enabling 3rd party Drive apps

Tags: google-drive-api

My domain currently does not allow 3rd party Drive apps. I don't see this changing any time soon.

Is there any way I can create a service account-based application using the Drive SDK and not enable all 3rd party Drive applications?

Comment: I didnt understand your question, enabling 3rd party apps are required for create/open with actions. Please clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: I have a drive app that I want to use to impersonate users [like so](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation). So far, to do so would require allowed installation of any 3rd party drive app in the world. This is no good. I want to use the Drive SDK in an internal admin type function, without enabling all 3rd party drive apps.